# How to find places near me within a specific radius

Tags: google-maps, react-native, google-maps-api-3, maps, google-geolocation

I am building a React Native app and would like to show places around for a specific shop, let say H&M shops I would like to show near device current location.

Are there any API for this that google provides so that you can search by shop name, address, postal code etc and that it can return all the cordinates and info for that address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Google provides alot of API's for different applications.

Have a look at https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search

Example:

> **Nearby search example**
>
> The following example is a search request for places of type 'restaurant' within a 1500m radius of a point in Sydney, Australia, containing the word 'cruise':
>
> ```
> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=1500&type=restaurant&keyword=cruise&key=YOUR_API_KEY
> ```
>
> **Note:** In this example, you need to replace the key with your own API key in order for the request to work in your application.

Comment: do u have any idea how can we add this into a react native app? or are there any library made already there for react native for nearBySearch

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html) and do some research on the internet on calling api's and displaying data

Comment: I am able to get what I wans from https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=60.16915,24.9293937&radius=20000&keyword=k+rauta&rankBy=distance&key=KEY but for some reason rankby distance is not working for me, any idea why?

Comment: Please read the documentation of google! `Specifies the order in which results are listed. Note that rankby must not be included if radius (described under Required parameters above) is specified.`

Comment: i removed radius and then I get no result! Is there a way that I can get the result in a ordered way by nearest the first!

Comment: If you use rankby=distance when not using radius=1234 that should work. And yet again, if you read the documentation all the answers on your question are in that documentation.

Comment: well for some reason not working for me and idk what I am missing, I know the documentation explains it, but i idk what I am missing from doc, can you provide the correct url for this? I am currently removing radius and addding rankby, also have type, keyword,name

Comment: This works for me if I fill in the right key `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=32.715738, -117.161084&rankby=distance&keyword=Grocery store&key=YOURKEY`

Comment: works for me, just noticed that i had 'rankBy' instead of 'rankby', thanks!

Comment: @RonNabuurs can I get a distance of all nearby locations from my current location?

Comment: @AhteshamShah I do recommend to read the documentation Google made